# get clients based user login name in linq?

Tags: vb.net, linq, linq-to-sql

How to retrieve clients based on username table using LINQ query?
[image]

Comment: Ok. What have you tried?

Comment: it seems that with the amount of rep you have, you shouldn't need to be directed to the FAQ for the site...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get a client based on username, something like this should work.

```
dim client = ( _
    From client In Dim_Client
    Where client.App_Users.Any(Function(user) user.Username = "foo")
    Select client).Single
```

Answer (score 1):

Search for the user with the desired user name and get the associated client.

```
Dim username = "Bob"
Dim clients =
    From user In db.App_Users
    Where user.Username = username
    Select user.Dim_Client
```